# Minecraft Server XP Shop Trouble

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to create an XP shop for a server I'm setting up. For this to work, I need to set a minimum level to make sure people that don't have enough levels can't buy the things they're not supposed to. My test command reads:

```
/give @p[lm=6] diamond
```

Pretty basic. The command works perfectly for single player. Only It keeps coming up with on the server:

```
[08:39:18] There is no such item with name minecraft:[lm=6]
```

So, why doesn't the "level minimum" command work on the server, and is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

Always make sure to copy and paste the commands, otherwise you can get problems like this from simple typos.

You probably had a space between `@p` and `[lm=6]`, that way Minecraft interprets `[lm=6]` as the item name.

Comment: I did copy paste. Furthermore, I tried it with, and without a space between and neither worked

Comment: Can you make a video? You definitely shouldn't get that error message without the space.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply because of how servers like bukkit, spigot, etc. have a custom /give command.

You need to type `/minecraft:give @p[lm=6] diamond` in order to use Minecraft's vanilla /give command which contains the "[lm=6]" tag in it's coding. Hope this helps!